# Form submittion using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

*When i want to submit this form to the preferred URL using ajax function, but problem is that URL is going empty.I am using PHP codeigniter framework, hmvc  .please anyone help me.There is form image.*

```
<div class="actionElement">
<div class="form-group oh">
<div class="col-md-12">
<?php
echo form_open(base_url("demand/demand/sendmailto/".$demandid)," id='saveSerializeMedicalMulti'");

?>
<form action="javascript:void(0);" data-action="<?php echo base_url("demand/demand/sendmailto/".$demandid);?>" id="maillistdata" class="maillistdata" method="post">  
<input type="text" value="<?php  var_dump($multiId); ?>" name="multiid" id="multiid">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $demandid; ?>" name="demandid" id="demandid" />
<div class="col-md-12 wrapper"><b>Company Name:<?php echo $this->demand_model->getCompanyName($result->NAME).'-'.$this->demand_model->getCountryById($result->COUNTRY); ?></b></div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-6">Pre Auth Date:<?php echo $result->PRE_AUTH_DATE;?></div>
<div class="col-md-6">Lot No:<?php echo $result->LOT_NO; ?> </div>
</div>

<h5>Vacancy List &nbsp <span class="fa fa-list-ul"></span> </h5> 
<table id="vacancyList" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th colspan="2">NOS</th>
            <th colspan="2">Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <th>Male</th>
    <th>Female</th> 
    <th>AED</th>
    <th>NRs.</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php if ($demand!=''){
        $cnt=0;
      foreach ($demand as $r_child) {


        ?>


    <td><?php echo ++$cnt; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r_child->POST_NAME;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r_child->M_QUANTITY;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r_child->F_QUANTITY;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r_child->FROEIGN_CURR;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r_child->NEPALI_CURR;?></td>
    </tr> 
    <?php }
    }?>                                                           

    </tbody>
</table>
 <!-- <div class="oh">
<a href="<?php echo base_url("demand/demand/sendmailto/".$demandid); ?>" class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="multiSave">Save demand</a>
</div> -->  
<!-- <button type="submit" id="sendmail" name="sendmail">Send Mail</button>  -->
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="sendmail" name="sendmail" >Send Mail</a>
<?php
         echo form_close();
?>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){

        $(document).on("click", "#sendmail", function(){
            //var url = $("#maillistdata").attr("action");
            var url = $(form).attr("action");

            var data = $('#maillistdata').serializeArray();
                        //alert($("#multiId").val());
                        alert(url);

            data.push({name : 'multiId', value: $("#multiId").val() });

        $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',                       
                url: url,
                data: data,
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.status==1){
                        $.gritter.add({
                            text: response.message
                        });
                        $("#multiId").val();
                        //alert($("#multiId").val());
                        bootbox.hideAll();
                        window.location = "<?php echo base_url().'demand/demand/sendmailto/'.$demandid; ?>"
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if(response.status==0){
                        var error=response.error.split("</p>");
                        for(var i=0;i<error.length;i++){
                            $.gritter.add({
                                text: error[i]
                            });
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    else{
                        $.gritter.add({
                            text: response.error
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });



 </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `data-action` instead of `action`. The attribute added to form tag is `data-action`. So you should use as below

```
var url = $(form).attr("data-action");
```

**Also you should remove this line :** `echo form_open(base_url("demand/demand/sendmailto/".$demandid)," id='saveSerializeMedicalMulti'");`. **Its creating duplicate form tag.**

Comment: i just use this  var url = $("#maillistdata").attr("data-action"); and alert it. it is giving message undefined

Comment: @SantoshSahani you should remove this line : `echo form_open(base_url("demand/demand/sendmailto/".$demandid)," id='saveSerializeMedicalMulti'");`. Its creating duplicate form tag

Comment: now i got url now i have another problem with the multiId.

Comment: Whats that problem @SantoshSahani

Comment: i have to send email to the selected agent. and multiId store all the id of the agent so that i can retieve email of the agent and send them email.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is duplicate form tag in your code. You are using codeigniter form helper form_open() and also placing a form tag your self. Refer line 5 and 8 of your code.

Comment: i just removed that. again tried but still url is undefined. in the url its shows # after id.